# Disable D3 zoom on circle PNG background

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to disable the D3 zoom on a particular element. This element happens to be the PNG background to a circle.

Right now this is not working. I have tried to offset the scale parameter in the zoom, but the background PNG still 'grows' with the circle. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/42q1gnho/1/).

**This is how I try to offset the zoom:**

```
d3.selectAll("#grump_avatar").attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/d3.event.scale + ")");
```

I know there are similar questions on SO, but please note none of them have received a satisfactory response thus far. Better luck here, hopefully.

Comment: Which element are you trying not to zoom?  `d3.selectAll("#grump_avatar")`, you don't have any elements with an id of `grump_avatar`.

Comment: There are three: `#grump_avatar1`, `#grump_avatar2` and `#grump_avatar3`. These are the PNG images used as a background behind each circle. The code does not work for any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of issues with this code:

1. Matching by id is an **exact** match.
2. Your `id`s are on `def` attributes, which aren't the objects, you don't want to scale (those would be the circles).
3. To match multiple objects, you should be using a `class` on the circles.
4. You apply the zoom directly to the `svg`, you should be wrapping everything in a `g`.  SVG handles the events, `g` is the zoomable "canvas".
5. Once you apply the zoom correctly you are going to lose your circle placement because you overwrite the `transform` without reapplying the `translate`.
6. You've made no use of `d3` data-binding, so you can't persist your data correctly.

All this in mind, here is how I would refactor your code:

```js
var config = {
  "avatar_size": 100
}

var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

var g = svg.append("g");

var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

data = [{
  posx: 100,
  posy: 100,
  img: "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-round-system/512/android-128.png",

}, {
  posx: 200,
  posy: 200,

  img: "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-set/24/Reverbnation-128.png"
}, {
  posx: 300,
  posy: 300,

  img: "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-128.png"
}];

defs.selectAll("pattern")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("pattern")
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "grump_avatar" + i)
  .attr("width", config.avatar_size)
  .attr("height", config.avatar_size)
  .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", (d) => d.img)
  .attr("width", config.avatar_size)
  .attr("height", config.avatar_size)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);

g.selectAll(".grump_avatar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "grump_avatar")
  .attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.posx + "," + d.posy + ")")
  .attr("cx", config.avatar_size / 2)
  .attr("cy", config.avatar_size / 2)
  .attr("r", config.avatar_size / 2)
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("fill", (d, i) => "url(#grump_avatar" + i + ")");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function() {

    g.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ') scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');

    d3.selectAll(".grump_avatar").attr("transform", (d) => {
      return "scale(" + 1 / d3.event.scale + ")" + "translate(" + (d.posx - d3.event.translate[0]) + "," + (d.posy - d3.event.translate[1]) + ")";
    });
  });
svg.call(zoom);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

**EDITS** based on comments:

To scale the circles opposite the zoom and position them, the key is:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .attr("transform", function(d){
    return 'scale(' + 1 / d3.event.scale + ')'; // inverse of scale for size 
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d){
    return d.x * d3.event.scale; // change position based on scale, d.x is the original unscaled position
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d){
    return d.y * d3.event.scale;
  });
```

Comment: Mark, thank you so much for this, I am working on your code. Just a quick question: how might I translate the 'grump avatar' using the coordinates of its parent circle, as opposed to the absolute position given by the data array?

Comment: @Noobster, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Right now you are performing a translation on .grump_avatar as a function of d.posx and d.posy. Can you achieve the same by using the cx and cy of the circle you have appended? How would you do that? I ask because the positioning of the circle may change.

Comment: Mark, I have created another jsFiddle that this time should better demonstrate the issue that I am experiencing. I don't think I even need to explain what the issue is, you'll see it straight off when you try zooming in on the map :) https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/Lo2mjhjq/3/

Comment: @Noobster, I understand what you are after now.  Take a look [at this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo2mjhjq/5/)

Comment: Hello Mark, this is the correct answer! Thank you. I will mark it as 'correct' if you provide it below.

Comment: @Noobster, edited the answer above to include the relevant parts.